Second order IVP with a parameter
I am working on this problem. I am studying for an exam.
Let $u_{\alpha}$ be the solution of the equation
\begin{equation}
u''(t) + F(t)u'(t) + (u(t))^5 - u(t) = 0,
\end{equation}
with initial conditions $u'(0) = 0$ and $u'(0) = \alpha$, where $t \in [0,1]$ and $F : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ is a $C^2$ positive function. Show that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exist an $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and a $t \in (0,\epsilon)$ such that $u'_{\alpha} = -1$.
What I have done is write this as
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} u\\
 w 
\end{pmatrix}' = \begin{pmatrix} w \\
 -F(t)w - u^5 + u 
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
with $u(0) = \alpha$ and $w(0) = 0$. By the Picard-Lindelof theorem, there is a unique solution. We can integrate the given condition $u_{\alpha}'(t) = -1$ to get $u_{\alpha}(t) = \alpha - t$. This solves the equation as long as $F(t) = (\alpha - t)^5 - (\alpha - t)$ because $w = -1$. Thus, this is the unique solution and will exist for any $\alpha$ as long as that is the initial condition.
But I think there is a lot missing. Why must $F$ be $C^2$ and positive? For the theorem, being $C^1$ suffices. The $\epsilon$ is trivially given because the interval where the unique solution exists must contain the initial condition, but there must be more to this problem. Any help is appreciated.
